# clearInterval does not stop the interval operation

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a timer, and would like the `setInterval()` operation to terminate when the counter reaches zero. Further, I would like the function to be "turned off" if you will, so that I can reset the value that is fed into the timer, without the timer starting to decrement again.

When I configure the code like this:

```js
    function countdown(){ 
        var intervalKill = setInterval(function(){
        var start = document.getElementById("startValue").innerHTML;
        if (start > 1){
            var time_left = start - 1;
            document.getElementById("startValue").innerHTML = time_left;
        } else if (start === 1) {
            clearInterval(intervalKill)
        }
        
    }, 1000);
    }
```

I get it running perfectly well, however if it reaches 1, and I reset the timer, it will start counting down instantly again.

When I code it like this:

```js
    function countdown(){ 
        var intervalKill = setInterval(function(){
        var start = document.getElementById("startValue").innerHTML;
        if (start > 1){
            var time_left = start - 1;
            document.getElementById("startValue").innerHTML = time_left;
        } else if (start === 1) {
            clearInterval(intervalKill);
            break;
        }
        
    }, 1000);
    }
```

The function just does not run at all. Can someone shed some light on what is going on here and how to get it to work?

Comment: You are comparing a string and a number.

Comment: @Li357 Is this because I am using the wrong equality operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function countdown(){ 
    var intervalKill = setInterval(function(){
    var start = document.getElementById("startValue").innerHTML;
    if (start > 1){
        var time_left = start - 1;
        document.getElementById("startValue").innerHTML = time_left;
    } else if (+start === 1) {
        clearInterval(intervalKill);
        // break;  <-- not necessary
    }

}, 1000);
}
```

Either parse the `start` to integer using unary + or `parseInt` or use `==` instead of `===` since the latter checks for type information as well.
`innerHTML` returns a string.

Comment: Thanks, it was still not executing when I had the break keyword in there. After I removed it it worked just fine. So the final solution ends up being make the change you suggest and remove the "break" keyword.

Comment: I don't think break will do anything, it is just not required.  It is usually used with loops or switch.